# Перевод строки в Windows и Linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, windows-7

Я работаю в Windows7, где у меня есть виртуалка с гостевой Ubuntu. Из W7 в Ubuntu прокинута общая папка. В Ubuntu выполняется скриптик на C++, который выводит результаты в файл в общей папке. Ну т.е. что-то типа `outFile << result << std::endl`. В результате почему-то получается так, что в Ubuntu есть переводы строки (смотрю в Vim), а в винде (Блокнот) нету. Как сделать так, чтобы файл и в Vim, и в Блокнот отображался одинаково?

Comment: Нету такого понятия «конец строки, чтобы выстраивалось в таблицу». Есть «Windows-нативные концы строк» (`\r\n`) и «Linux-нативные концы строк» (`\n`). Какие из них ваши программы воспримут как концы строк — зависит от ваших программ.

Comment: Ну а вот std::endl ? Он же и в винде, и в линуксе одинаково работает?

Comment: Нет, не одинаково. Он для случая файла, открытого как текстовый, выставляет системно-специфические концы строк.

Comment: Но ведь пишется то одинаково, хоть где работай! Я и в Ubuntu могу в vim написать std::endl, и в W7 в Блокноте могу также написать! Почему пишется одинаково, а работает по-разному?

Comment: Если я под Ubuntu напишу \r\n, будет ли у меня файл в обеих ОС отображаться идентично?

Comment: ??? Если вы в vim напишете std::endl, вы увидите только буквы.

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз первый комментарий. Это зависит от конкретной программы.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько вариантов.

1. В ubuntu есть программы fromdos/todos, конвертирующие символы завершения строк.
2. При открытии файла в windows можно использовать бинарный режим (а в unix он просто всегда бинарный) когда \n не переводится в \r\n и тогда писаться будет одинаково в обеих системах, а в программе писать \r\n вместо \n.
3. Тот же бинарный формат, но оставить \n, если используемые программы в windows и так понимают.

См. флаг ios::binary в fstream или b в fopen

Comment: Вопрос был `std::endl`, как ваш ответ с ним связан?

Comment: `std::endl` в программе на С просто заменяется нужной строкой, в зависимости от ОС, из под которой программа запущена. Если Вы запускаете программу из-под Linux, программа будет писать `\n`, если из под Windows - `\r\n`. Почти наверняка это поведение можно переопределить, но зачем?

Comment: @Cerbo `std::endl` и `'\n'` дают один результат, преобразование \n в \r\n закопано глубже

Comment: и его можно отключить, как я написал

Comment: Упс, похоже прав все же @sercxjo. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/ А еще точнее, похоже правы мы оба, т.к. стандартная библиотека должна заменять `'\n'` на корректный символ/символы перевода строки: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520900/portable-end-of-line